# Prove that projection operator is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis

[Ciarlet (2.2-4)] Let $K$ be a compact subset of a normed vector space $(X, \Vert \cdot\Vert)$.

(1) Show that, given any $x \in X$, there exists $y \in K$ such that $\Vert x - y\Vert = \inf_{z \in K}\Vert x - z\Vert$.

(2) Show that, if in addition $y$ is unique for each $x \in X$, the mapping $P: X \rightarrow K$ defined by $\Vert x - Px\Vert = \inf_{z \in K} \Vert x - z\Vert$ for each $x \in X$ is continuous.

For the first question, I think it only needs to prove that the mapping $z \mapsto \Vert x - z\Vert$ is continuous. I was confused about the second question. I know how to prove this claim in Hilbert space with the help of the inner product defined on it, but the same idea seems doesn't work here.

Comment: Isn't it enough for the first question to say that compact subspace is closed, therefore such $y$ exists?

Comment: For the second part of the question you can consider sequences $x_n \to x$ and $Px_n \to y$ and show that $Px = y$.

Comment: @PaulSnopov: Thank you for your comment. I think you're correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, compactness of $K$ and continuity of $z\mapsto \|x-z\|$ is enough.

For the second question :

- **Lemma** :  The mapping $d(x,K) = \inf_{z\in K}\| x-z\|$ is continuous (without the assumption of unicity of $P(x)$ : for $z\in K$ and $x,y \in X$, we have :
  $$ \| x-z\| \leq \|x-y\| +\|y-z\| \leq \|x-y\| + d(y,K)$$
  therefore $d(x,K) \leq \|x-y\|+ d(y,K)$ and $|d(x,K) - d(y,K)|\leq \|x-y\|$.
- Now, let us assume that $Px$ is well defined (i.e. the lower bound on $\|x-z\|$ is reached for a unique $z\in K$). Let $x_n \to x$ be a convergent sequence in $X$. Then :
  $$d(x_n,K) = \|x_n-Px_n\|\to d(x,K) = \| x - Px\|$$
  If $(x_{\varphi(n)})$ is a subsequence such that $(Px_{\varphi(n)})$ converges to $z\in K$, then $\| x - z\| = \|x-Px\|$ and therefore $Px = z$. The sequence $(Px_n)$ is bounded and has only one limit point $Px$. Therefore $\lim Px_n = Px$ and $P$ is continuous.

Comment: There might be some problems in $d(x_n, K) = \Vert x_n - Px_n \Vert$. Because, as you said, without the uniqueness of $y$, the operator seems not be well-defined. And the equality may not hold anymore.

Comment: I added the hypothesis of uniqueness where it becomes useful